# Как суммировать корзину с объектами товаров ее методом JavaScript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Мне надо заполнить объект корзины объектами товаров и суммировать стоимость корзины ее методом.

Я сделал так:

```
let basket = {
    sumBasket: function() {
        let sum = 0;
        for(var prop in this) {
            if(prop != "sumBasket") {
                sum = sum + prop.count * prop.price;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
};

let smartphone = {
    price: 320,
    count: 2
};

let refrigerator = {
    price: 840,
    count: 1
};

let television = {
    price: 550,
    count: 3
};

function addToBasket(items) {
    return (basket = {
        ...basket,
        ...items
    });
};

addToBasket({smartphone, refrigerator, television});

console.log(basket);

basket.sumBasket();

console.log(basket.sum);
```

Но у меня `sum` получается `NaN`, так как `prop.count` и `prop.price` - `undefined`

Наверно я не правильно обращаюсь к свойствам товаров. Помогите как надо?

Comment: Мне надо разобраться не только со свойствами, а именно сделать корзину, и я уже получил правильный ответ

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы обращаетесь к свойству `sum` в `console.log(basket.sum);` но у Вас этого свойства нет в объекте поэтому `undefined`.
2. `props` в `for(var prop in this)` это только ключ к объекту , а не сам объект. `prop.count` тоже `undefined`. Чтоб получить обект нужно `this[props]`

Вот мои предложения

```
const basket = {
  sum: 0, // свойство, чтоб было к чему обращаться
  goods: {}, // cоздайте отдельное свойство где будут лежать товары
  sumBasket: function () {
    let sum = 0;
    for (var key in this.goods) {
      const elem = this.goods[key]; // получить товар по ключу
      sum += elem.count * elem.price;
    }
    this.sum = sum; // запись свойста
    return sum;
  }
};

const smartphone = {
  price: 320,
  count: 2
};

const refrigerator = {
  price: 840,
  count: 1
};

const television = {
  price: 550,
  count: 3
};

basket.goods = { smartphone, refrigerator, television };

basket.sumBasket();

console.log(basket.sum);
```